# Search for test when the line begins with a particular word

Tags: python, regex

I need to search for a specific word when the beginning of a line starts with a particular word. For example:

Below is my Test String:

```
Switch      : 800215-00-02 0805G-00232 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 1.0.3.1    IMG: 15.3.1.4
PSU         : 700214-00-05 YT675-00893 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 3.0.2.9    IMG: 19.3.6.9
```

Now here I want to search for "0805G-00232" only where the line is starting with the word "Switch". I can search for just "0805G-00232" using regex \w{5}-\w{5} but that will include PSU as well and I don't want that.

Comment: What environment/programming language are you working in?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Why not just search for "^Switch: 0805G-00232.*$"?

Comment: Is that 1 string? A list of strings? It makes a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the beginning of the line followed by `Switch`, followed by any characters, followed by `\w{5}-\w{5}` *in a group*, then extract that group:

```
import re
strs = [
  'Switch : 800215-00-02 0805G-00232 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 1.0.3.1 IMG: 15.3.1.4',
  'PSU: : 700214-00-05 YT675-00893 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 3.0.2.9 IMG: 19.3.6.9'
]
regex = '^Switch.+(\w{5}-\w{5})'
for str in strs:
  result = re.compile(regex).search(str)
  if result is not None:
    print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, that will include other characters as well in between "Switch" and "0805G-00232"

Comment: That's why you need to select the *first group*, not the whole match

Comment: Understood. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> print st
Switch      : 800215-00-02 0805G-00232 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 1.0.3.1    IMG: 15.3.1.4
PSU         : 700214-00-05 YT675-00893 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 3.0.2.9    IMG: 19.3.6.9
```

You can use a regex to filter on the various lines:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: re.search(r'^Switch\s+:\s*.*0805G-00232', s),st.splitlines())
['Switch      : 800215-00-02 0805G-00232 Rev 2.0 BootROM: 1.0.3.1    IMG: 15.3.1.4']
```

Comment: Thanks..I will try that